# Why truncate a password hash to 14 characters?

Tags: database, security, passwords, hash

I'm working on some code, and at some point it's preparing a password to be stored in a database.  In rough pseudocode it's doing the following:

```
encrypted_password = truncate(hash(password), 14)
```

I.e. Computing the hash of the password, then truncating the hash to 14 characters.

---

Does anyone know why the application would truncate the hash in this way?  It's very deliberate so I'm suspecting it's to make the hash compatible with some fairly standard type of password store that I'm unaware of.

(Please ignore that this isn't a great way to store passwords, no salting, etc..)

Comment: If it's storing it in a database, perhaps whoever designed it created a `char(14)` column ... why I wouldn't know

Comment: Not AOL, but the authoring company are a Microsoft Certified Partner. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that I can think of is to maintain compatibility with some legacy system.  In fact, that would be the only reason that I can think of to make conscious decisions to sacrifice security in any event.

Consider a network that has insanely old UNIX boxes, for example, that are only capable of using eight character passwords with the classic crypt() function.  In order for them to perform authentication against other systems, or for other systems to perform authentication against those legacy UNIX systems, everyone has to manipulate the authentication data using the same method.

In fact, the only reason to transmit passwords (hashed, hashed + salted, or otherwise) over the network is in order to adhere to a legacy system or a system that otherwise has what I would call "legacy requirements".  The same goes for systems that are otherwise relatively weak in the security sense.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct - though I have no way currently to determine if this is the real reason.